# Internal proccess behind execution of Java program

Tags: jvm, java

I wanted to know the step-by-step internal process that happens on execution of a java program.

Example if we giv **java test** in command prompt.
What all process got invoked?
How JVM is instantiated ?   till it prints the output..

Comment: Take a look at the [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)...

Comment: This is a *very* large subject.  What do you want to know in particular?

Comment: Just a flow.. How jvm got instantiated.. Then next wat is called.. something like this..

Comment: Like @zeller mentioned, you should see JVM spec, and more specifically: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2

Answer (score 2):

The execution of java code internally will be in the following steps:-

```
Execution Command -->java Test
   1.Start JVM
   2.Create and Start Main Thread
   3.Look at Test.class File-->Main Thread is responsible for checking if not found Runtime Exception will occur saying Exception in Thread Main
   4.Load Test.class file
   5.Execute Main method
   6.Unload Test.class
   7.Terminate Main Thread
   8.Shut down JVM
```

Answer (score -2):

I dont know but however, the concept that i have understood , I will explain you the same....

Initially, the very first when you enter the command **java abc**(filename is abc.java) to run the program....the program will search for Java Runtime Environment as you have entered command (JAVA in cmd)....it means the path that you have set in Environment Variable....

Then the JVM is activated........JVM will give a call to the class loader.......then the class loader will go to the operating system to take a permission for the program execution.....once OS allows.....class loader will check the file name and the program name........(As you know the class name and file name should be same)........If everything goes fine........program is loaded in the Memory.....:)

Cheers :)

Shankar Salunkhe

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you possibly improve your formatting a little? All the periods are making this seem a little messy, even though the content seems to be OK. Maybe you could use a bullet-list or something as well (You can edit you post clicking "edit" below it).

Comment: In no English sentence should more than three periods be used consecutively. You use eight, multiple times. You also lack spaces between words, and use unnecessary caps (it's "Java", not "JAVA"). Your question also lacks clarity.